# fetching Windows phone 8.1 properties using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8.1

i have plugged my Windows phone 8.1 to my PC with USB.i want to fetch the device properties like Device manufacturer ,resolution and serial id.how  can we do it using visual c++ or using c#

Comment: Please try to Google it first, we are here resolve your issues, not to do code for you.

Comment: @TirthakShah .do you have an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry dear Its is not possible till now to get or fetch this information though windows phone 8.1 /windows.

Comment: we have "System defined setup class" for USB devices ,disk drivers.i want to know if any how we can  fetch something for windows phone..here is the code

Comment: ManagementObjectCollection collection;
      using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume")) // WHERE InterfaceType='USB' Win32_MemoryDevice
        collection = searcher.Get();      

      foreach (var device in collection)
      {
         // ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + device["DeviceID"] + "'");
        devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
        device["SerialNumber"].ToString()));
      }

Comment: Is this code run on windows phone 8.1 enviroment coz i think this code for winform win32 application.?????

Comment: no..i want to fetch any windows phone device information connected to my system.i am using win32 console application for this